# How to create PDF using gridview content in android?

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, pdf-generation

I am trying to create pdf file using gridview content and it's working fine but when I have open it only shows visible area data line 2 row and two columns in the center?

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="595pt"
            android:layout_height="842pt"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:columnWidth="320dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:stretchMode="none"
                android:verticalSpacing="1dp">

            </GridView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I expect the full content will be visible in pdf. I am providing A4 size pdf size to linearlayout.

**Expected Result**

[image: Grid View in activity]

**Actual Result Got after PDF creation**

[image]

Comment: I think you need to remove your fixed `layout_height` and `layout_width` of `LinearLayout`

Comment: No, I need that to fill full content in A4 size PDF also with the help of it I have to calculate numberOfRows and columns?